# how to create variable step using html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using html5 and javascript. i want to divide the range 0 to 200000 into different sections, say 4, and each section having differnt step size. I have found out this. But didnt find how to get variable step size

```
<input 
    id="slide" 
    type="range" 
    min="0" 
    max="200000" 
    step="1" 
    value="100000" 
    onchange="updateSlider(this.value)" >
```

Comment: Please stop using inline js. https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS535US535&oq=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.1638j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: just pass this, and in function read its value

Comment: Adding inline event handlers is not a good practice. We should keep the behavior(js), presentation(css) and content(markup) separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass this, and in function read its value

e.g. using javascript

```
<input 
id="slide" 
type="range" 
min="0" 
max="200000" 
step="1" 
value="100000" 
onchange="updateSlider(this)" />

function updateSlider(c)
{
    if(c.value <=  50000)
  {
    if(c.step != 1)
        c.step = 1;
    alert(c.value);
  }
  else 
  {
     if(c.step != 3)
        c.step = 3;
    alert(c.value);
  }
}
```

here you can check on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lyfva/7/, here i make a check now, it will change step only when certain condition is satisfied.

Comment: OP is not using jquery

Comment: Is it possible to have different step size for differnt range. say 0 to 50000 must have a step size of 1. 50001 to 100000 may have a step size of 3.

Comment: @Arun : is it by updating the step attribte every time there is an event change? I dontknow to do this updation. Or is it checking the value returned by this.value

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using javascript. Why not use a better way.

### Try this [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/AGuSUFo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

### HTML

```
  <input 
    id="slide" 
    type="range" 
    min="0" 
    max="200000" 
    step="1" 
    value="100000" />
```

### Javascript

```
var input = document.getElementById('slide');
input.onchange = updateSlider;

function updateSlider(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
```